# Adding to a solr document/entry from multiple sources

Tags: solr

If I have multiple sets of information from different documents that goes with the same primary key, how can I upload to solr so that material is added without removing previous information. For instance, if I have two files

id,phone
fred77,111-222-333

and

id,fullname
fredd77, Fred Flintstone

how can I make the database show fred77 with BOTH pieces of information?

Should I be looking at this differently overall for a better solr smart implementation?

Comment: look into solr atomic updates.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use atomic updates.
Here is the link: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates
Look at Yonik's page : http://heliosearch.org/solr/atomic-updates/